# How can I get the next immediate tag with HTML::Tokeparser?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get the tags that occur immediately after a particular `div` tag. For e.g., I have html code

```
<div id="example">
     <h2>Example</h2>
     <p>Hello !World</p>
</div>
```

I'm doing the following,

```
while ( $tag = $stream->get_tag('div') ) {
    if( $tag->[1]{id} eq 'Example' ) {
        $tag = $stream->get_tag;
        $tag = $stream->get_tag;
        if ( $tag->[0] eq 'div' ) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

But this throws the error
`Can't use string ("</h2>") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`

It works fine if I say 
`$tag = $stream->get_tag('h2');`
`$tag = $stream->get_tag('p');`

But I can't have that because I need to get the immediate two tags and verify if they are what i expect them to be.

Comment: Side note: you might like HTML::TokeParser::Simple better -- it's exactly the same parser, but it returns token *objects* instead of arrayrefs that you have to do silly things to to get data out of :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to tell if you posted a runnable example program, but it looks like the problem is you didn't realize that `get_tag` returns both start *and* end tags.  End tags don't have attributes.  Start tags are returned as `[$tag, $attr, $attrseq, $text]`, and end tags are returned as `["/$tag", $text]`.

Comment: I see. so in this case get_tag returns h2,/h2,div etc. yes?

Comment: @Rajesh, Yes. And if you try to do `$tag->[1]{id}` on an end tag, you'll get that error, because `$tag->[1]` is not a hash ref.  You have to check `$tag->[0]` first to see whether you have a start or end tag whenever you use `get_tag` with either no tag list, or a tag list that includes end tags.